# SQL group counts per section and show records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm looking for some pointers in how to group my results on two items, Sites and Assets and showing the results for all records. The table structure is pretty simple.

**Tables**

```
[Sites] ID | SiteName
[SiteAssets] ID | SiteID | AssetName
[SiteAssetCosts] ID | SiteAssetID | CostName | Value
```

> I'm hoping to return a table with one SQL statement that shows:

```
SiteName1  | SUM(SiteAssetCost.Value)
AssetName1 | SUM(SiteAssetCost.Value)
CostName1  | [SiteAssetCost.Value]
CostName2  | [SiteAssetCost.Value]
CostName3  | [SiteAssetCost.Value]

AssetName2 | SUM(SiteAssetCost.Value)
CostName1  | [SiteAssetCost.Value]
CostName2  | [SiteAssetCost.Value]

SiteName2  | SUM(SiteAssetCost.Value)
AssetName1 | SUM(SiteAssetCost.Value)
CostName1  | [SiteAssetCost.Value]
CostName2  | [SiteAssetCost.Value]
```

Etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See if this comes close to what you want:

```
select s.sitename, sa.assetname, sac.costname, sum(value) as value
from siteassetcosts sac join
     siteassets sa
     on sac.siteassetid = sa.id join
     sites s
     on sa.siteid = s.id
group by s.sitename, sa.assetname, sac.costname with rollup;
```

Comment: You life saver. Strangely enough I did look at using rollup but for some reason I must of had a brain fart moment or 3 and didn't look any further into it. Works perfectly. Thanks a billion Gordon.

Comment: aah yeah I've just realized it's only going to show a sum for records that exist in Costs. I need to figure out a way to have a count of 0 for the assets that don't have costs. So the rollup doesn't need to happen if there are no Costs records.

Comment: @JT... . . . If `left join` doesn't do what you want, then ask *another* question, with sample data and desired results.